# Auto Renew Membership

Tags: civimember

Brand new to CiviCRM. First thing I am trying to setup is memberships. Our members dues are automatically deducted from paychecks. We receive 26 paychecks per year but only 24 dues payments per year. So no dues are collected from the 3rd paycheck within a calendar month (happens twice a year)  Trying to figure out the best term to use and if there is a way to just allow the payments to be automatically recorded in CiviCRM based on the schedule dates for paychecks or to just simplify it to 2 payments per month... No payments actually need to be processed, just simply recorded in CiviCRM.

Initially it seemed that it might just be easier to not track actual payments and just override the members status and just manually expire the member when they resign but trying to use CiviCRM to its fullest extent.

Comment: Do you receive a file listing these payments?  How do members join and leave?  Should their membership status in Civi depend on the payments being received?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE.

I think you have quite a complicated membership processing structure there (very frequent payments), but the basic requirement seems to be process membership update structure from an external file (I presume you get the paycheck info as a CSV file) is quite common. If you don't need to record the payments at all I think you can do a membership import to update the membership expiry dates (you would need to do a bit of processing on the file first to indicate the appropriate expiry date.

If you want to record the payments (as I do) then its a bit more difficult and I haven't yet found a good solution ([How to bulk renew membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/424/how-to-bulk-renew-membership) is similar).

Comment: Actually I think my solution in the linked question is OK, having tried it in anger and realising how many special cases there are.